# Show that such an $f$ cannot exist

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> Suppose $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a scalar field, such that for a given vector $a\in\mathbb R^n$ and any $y\in\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$ we have, $f'(a;y)>0$. Show that such a function $f$ cannot exist.

The exercise is taken from Apostol Calculus Vol. 2. I am a beginner in the subject so I want to ensure that my arguments and understanding are absolutely clear. Here is my solution:

> By definition, $$f'(a;y)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(a+hy)-f(a)}{h}$$ and by assumption, as $f'(a;y)>0$, we have $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(a+hy)-f(a)}{h}>0$$
>
> Taking $-y$ instead of $y$ we have $f'(a;-y)>0$ by assumption, hence, $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(a-hy)-f(a)}{h}>0$$. Taking $t=-h$ and noting that $h\to0$ implies $t\to0$, we can say that $$\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{f(a+ty)-f(a)}{-t}>0\implies \lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{f(a+ty)-f(a)}{t}<0\implies f'(a;y)<0$$ which is an obvious contradiction.
>
> Hence no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Yes your solution is correct. I would say that $f'(a, \cdot) : \Bbb{R}^k \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is linear, hence it cannot be always positive.

Comment: You should write $y\neq 0$, otherwise it fails.

Comment: I was able to make out a physical interpretation of this problem. A function $f$ cannot be both increasing or decreasing at a point $a$. However, by the assumptions in the problem, the function value increases as $x$ moves from $a$ to $a+hy$ and the function value hence decreases if $x$ moves from $a$ to $a-hy$, which is contradicted if we take $-y$ instead of $y$.

Comment: @GitGud My bad, it was mentioned in the exercise. I will edit the question.

Comment: @GitGud What fails if $y=0$ is permitted?  In fact, if $y=0$ is permitted, we see immediately that $f'>0$ always is refuted.  Are you suggesting that the case with $y=0$ permitted is the trivial case?  That is true.

Comment: @Dr.MV The statement is (was) of the form $\forall a\forall y(\text{Something})$. The OP's argument first takes an arbitrary $a$ and then showcases a $y$ for which $\forall y(\text{Something})$ fails. Only the OP didn't specify any $y$, it was implicit that any $y$ would do, and although that's true, $0$ wouldn't do for different reasons than those that the OP specified.

Comment: @GitGud The "showcased" $y$ was arbitrary, was it not?  And the case $y=0$ fails immediately.  So, perhaps you're correct.  The OP did proceed, tacitly assuming that $y\ne 0$ to continue the proof.  I thought you meant that if $y$ was permissible that there was a problem in showing that there exists no such $f$ with $f'>0$ always.  Good catch!

Comment: I am extremely interested to understand why $y=0$ fails. In my argument, I had to assume $y\neq0$ otherwise the things with $-y$ wouldn't have worked. Could you kindly enlighten me on why, in general, $y=0$ would fail? By the way, my $a$ is fixed, not arbitrary.

Comment: Because $f'(a,0)=0$ for any $f$ and any $a$.

Comment: Of course!! So stupid of me!!